# Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor in super()

Tags: java

I'm following a guide on how to create a working interface in Java and I've done the code according to the guide yet I get an error saying `Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor`, even though it is the first statement.
I tried multiple solutions so I'm quite lost as none of them worked.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class test extends JFrame {                  
    private JLabel item1;
    private void test () {
        super ("Title 1"); //error happens here     
      }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You didn't create a constructor - constructors don't have return type of void. It should be

```
private test (){  
    super ("Title 1");  
}
```

but you actually should stick to Java naming conventions and rename your class to `Test`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I actually believe I've tried that but it did not work, removing 'void' fixed my issue however ^^

Answer (score 2):

The constructor should not have a return value

```
private test () {
    super(); // This should do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `void` from your `test` function.

Your code must be like:

```
public test (){
    super ("Frame Title");
}
```